# Java: printf stack error

Tags: java

I was trying to convert from println to printf and this is what I got.

```
//*********************************Output File*********************************
//Create a file with the information entered 
//and the information processed
 public void outputFile() throws IOException{
String payFileOutput=null;
PrintWriter file= new PrintWriter("DataOutput.txt");
file.printf("Your total expenses per month are %10f\n", 
   format.format(getTotalCost()));
file.printf("Your college tuition is %10f\n", format.format(getTuition()));
file.printf("Your rent is %10f\n", format.format(getRent()));
  if(pay==1)
   payFileOutput="Savings";
  else if(pay==2)
   payFileOutput="Loans";
  else if(pay==3)
   payFileOutput="Freelance Work";
  else
   ;
  file.printf("Your payment method is %10f\n", payFileOutput);
  file.printf("Your amount entered for the payment method is %10f\n", 
     format.format(getPayment()));
  if(totalCost<0){
   file.printf("You still need: %5f per month\n", 
     format.format(getTotalCost()));}
  else{
   file.printf("\nYour budget seems good");}
  file.close();
 }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4011)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2738)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2683)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2449)
 at java.io.PrintWriter.format(PrintWriter.java:878)
 at java.io.PrintWriter.printf(PrintWriter.java:777)
 at FinanceRev1.outputFile(FinanceRev1.java:173)
 at FinanceGUI$button2Listener.actionPerformed(FinanceGUI.java:286)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6175)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5940)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4536)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4362)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4125)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4362)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:604)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

---

**Update**: the solution: Number format formatted the indicated number to a String, and because I had %f (float) it was pretty  obvious I would get a stack since you cant reference a string to a float. Thanks to HydroKirby on MIrC.

Comment: Telling us which line is line 173 would be immensely helpful.

Comment: If this is homework, then please mark accordingly.

Comment: Put a try{...}catch(IllegalFormatConversionException ifce) { System.out.println(ifce.getMessage()); } around the code. What does it give?

Comment: put it around line 173 or around the entire method ?

Comment: skip the try/catch -- it already shows you exactly what the problem is!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DXgxFSJF  this is what the try catch says

Comment: well what should I do then?? line 173 seems correct syntax wise

Comment: @Andrei Put those pastebin posts in here so they can be helpful to others. And wrap the stack trace in code blocks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In

```
file.printf("Your payment method is %10f\n", payFileOutput);
```

the type of `payFileOutput` is String, whereas the `%10f` format specifier is expecting to consume a float, hence your tip error:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
```

That particular line is one that would give rise to this error, but your calls to `format()` may also produce similar mismatches if the return type of that method were also String.

Comment: @Andrei - looking at your pastebin code I see you're using NumberFormat.format() at line 173 - which is where the error is thrown - that returns a String.  You'll need to change all use of '%f' where you provide a String to printf, not just the one instance detailed.